# append hardcoded value in f.select_tag in rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a dropdown in my rails partial which onchange calling a remote function...I am using rails2.3 verison.. In the drop down I am retreiving list of students like this..

```
<%= select :students, :id,
                     @students.map {|s| [s.name, s.id] },
                     {:prompt => "Select A Student"},
                     {:onchange => "#{remote_function(
                             :url => { :action => 'type' },
                             :method => 'get',
                             :with => "'stud_id='+value",
                             :before => "Element.show('loader')",
                             :success => "Element.hide('loader')"  )}"} %>
```

This is working fine... I get list of students with their ids as values.. But I need to add one more option as "All students" to the dropdown so that I can view the details of all the students. How would I achieve it. Please put your thoughts on this as I am new to rails and learning it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.  Instead of using

```
@students.map {|s| [s.name, s.id] }
```

you can simply add a blank item to the array

```
[["All students",'']] + @students.map {|s| [s.name, s.id] }
```

I forget if Rails 2 allows you to do an { include_blank: true }, it is available in later versions.

Comment: Glad it worked out.  I should have included the 'all students' option, I updated my answer to include it.